# I cannot get my output to read NumberOfTopings, i think because its an int. I dont really know how to proper format the string to take the int

Tags: java

So I need to this to end up as 
Name : Bruce
Pizza Size: m
Number of Toppings: 3
Total charge : 14.25

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


    public class Week5

    {

        private static double calculateCharge(String PizzaSize, int toppings)

                {
                    int NumberOfTopings = 0;                                                                                                                            //Declaring Number of Toppings
                    final double SmallToping = 0.75;                                                                                                                    //Declaring Base charge of pizza
                    final double MediumToping = 1.25;
                    final double LargeToping = 1.75;                                                                                                                    //Declaring Charge Per Topping in decimal
                    double Charge = 0;                                                                                                                                  //Declaring Charge of item
                    final double Small = 6.50;
                    final double Medium = 10.50;
                    final double Large = 14.50;                                                                                                                         //Declaring Base charge of pizza
                    final int n = 3;
                    double TotalTopings = 0;
                    double average= 0;
                    double TotalCharge = 0;
                    int totalScore = 0 ;
                    int count = 1;


                                if (PizzaSize.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))                                                                                                    // if statement to calculate if you order a small medium or large pizza order and the following size od sides on pizza
                                {
                                    Charge = Small + (NumberOfTopings * SmallToping);
                                }
                                    else if (PizzaSize.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
                                {
                                    Charge = Medium + (NumberOfTopings * MediumToping);
                                }
                                    else if (PizzaSize.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
                                {
                                    Charge = Large + (NumberOfTopings * LargeToping);
                                }

                                    return Charge ;

                }

    public static void main (String [] args)

        {

            int NumberOfTopings = 0;                                                                                                                                    //Declaring Number of Toppings
            final double SmallToping = 0.75;                                                                                                                            //Declaring Base charge of pizza
            final double MediumToping = 1.25;
            final double LargeToping = 1.75;                                                                                                                            //Declaring Charge Per Topping in decimal
            double Charge = 0;                                                                                                                                          //Declaring Charge of item
            final double Small = 6.50;
            final double Medium = 10.50;
            final double Large = 14.50;                                                                                                                                 //Declaring Base charge of pizza
            final int n = 3;
            double TotalTopings = 0;
            double average= 0;
            double TotalCharge = 0;
            int totalScore = 0 ;
            int count = 1;
            int toppings = 0;

                Scanner inNumber= new Scanner (System.in);                                                                                                              //Crate Scanner for input of number of toppings
                Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                                //Creat Scanner for input of Name of Customers


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "                 Rocky WoodFired Pizzas Entry System                    ");


                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < n)
                    {
                                                                                                                                                                        // do something
                        i++;

                                String CustomerName = (" ") ;
                            CustomerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter customers name");

                                String PizzaSize = " ";
                            PizzaSize = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter small, medium or large (\"s\",\"m\",\"l\")" + CustomerName);



                            int anInteger = NumberOfTopings;
                                    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter number of toppings for "));                                        //out putting customers name and number of toppings


                                if (PizzaSize.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))                                                                                                    // if statement to calculate if you order a small medium or large pizza order and the following size od sides on pizza
                            {
                                Charge = Small + (NumberOfTopings * SmallToping);
                            }
                                else if (PizzaSize.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
                            {
                                Charge = Medium + (NumberOfTopings * MediumToping);
                            }
                                else if (PizzaSize.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
                            {
                                Charge = Large + (NumberOfTopings * LargeToping);
                            }

                        Charge = calculateCharge(PizzaSize, toppings);
                        //String.format("Format string", args);


                        String.format("%s\n%s\n%d\n$%.2f",CustomerName, PizzaSize, NumberOfTopings, Charge);



                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format("---Rocky WoodFired Pizza's Reciept--- \nCustomer Name: " + CustomerName
                                                                                                    + "\nPizza Size: " + PizzaSize
                                                                                                    + "\nNumber of Toppings : " + (" " + NumberOfTopings)
                                                                                                    + "\nTotal Charge: " + Charge)) ;

                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format("%d" + "Number of Toppings: " + NumberOfTopings));
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Charge" + " $%.2f", Charge) ;




                        int currentScore = NumberOfTopings;
                        TotalTopings = TotalTopings + currentScore;

                        double CurrentCharge = Charge;
                        TotalCharge = TotalCharge + CurrentCharge;

                    }


            average = TotalTopings * 1.0 / n;
            TotalCharge = TotalCharge ;


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average number of     toppings per pizza is " + average + "\nThe total Charge Collected is " +  TotalCharge );





        }

    }




enter code here
```

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong, and which statement has the problem?

Comment: It is not clear where is the problem. Also, reduce the remove blank lines, reduce indentation and remove commented lines in order to be easier to read your code.